# How to make CAST(datetime) SQL Server function using Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I have an expression `CAST(0x0000A95A00B97B34 AS DateTime)` which is `2018-09-13 11:15:19.000`. How to make this CAST manually with Python? I've figured out that first 8 digits in dec format is the number of days since 01.01.1900 but the time is wrong. Here is my cast function.

```
def castDateTime(hexVal):
    hexDate = hexVal[2:10]
    hexTime = hexVal[10:]
    intDate = int(hexDate, 16)
    intTime = int(hexTime, 16)
    Date = datetime.strptime("00:00:00", "%H:%M:%S") + timedelta(days=intDate) + timedelta(milliseconds=intTime)
    return Date

print castDateTime('0x0000A95A00B97B34')
```

retrun: `2018-09-13 03:22:35.700000`
actual value `2018-09-13 11:15:19.000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've gathered, the first two bytes are the number of days since 1st Jan 1900; the last 2 bytes are then number of ticks since midnight, where 1 tick is equal to 1/300th of a second.

As such, the following should yield the correct result:

```
def castDateTime(hexVal):
    hexDate = hexVal[2:10]
    hexTime = hexVal[10:]
    intDate = int(hexDate, 16)
    intTime = int(hexTime, 16) / 300
    Date = datetime.strptime("00:00:00", "%H:%M:%S") + timedelta(days=intDate) + timedelta(seconds=intTime)
    return Date
```